# reduce_max function in tensorflow

Tags: machine-learning, argmax

Screenshot

```
>>> boxes = tf.random_normal([ 5])
>>> with s.as_default():
...     s.run(boxes)
...     s.run(keras.backend.argmax(boxes,axis=0))
...     s.run(tf.reduce_max(boxes,axis=0))
...
array([ 0.37312034, -0.97431135,  0.44504794,  0.35789603,  1.2461706 ],
    dtype=float32)
3
0.856236
```

.

Why am I getting 0.8564. I expect the value to be 1.2461. since 1.2461 is big.right?

```
I am getting correct answer if i use tf.constant.
But I am not getting correct answer while using radom_normal
```

Comment: Please don't include text as pictures or images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time a new `boxes` is regenerated when you run `s.run()` with `radom_normal`. So your three results are different. If you want to get consistent results, you should only run `s.run()` once.

```
result = s.run([boxes,keras.backend.argmax(boxes,axis=0),tf.reduce_sum(boxes,axis=0)])
print(result[0])
print(result[1])
print(result[2])

#print
[ 0.69957364  1.3192859  -0.6662426  -0.5895929   0.22300807]
1
0.9860319
```

In addition, the code should be given in text format rather than picture format.

Comment: Thank you.
sorry for image.Actually new to stackoverflow., Now i changed that to text :-)

Comment: @Bubeshp It doesn't matter. Welcome to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow is different from numpy because TF only uses *symbolic operations*. That means when you instantiate the `random_normal`, you don't get numeric values, but a symbolic normal distribution, so **each time you evaluate it, you get different numbers**.

Each time you operate with this distribution, with any other operation, you are getting different numbers, and that explains the results you see.

Comment: Thank you! Now I understood.   Sorry for putting image...Actually new to stackoverflow